# Apache Frontend to tomcat:8443

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, tomcat, apache2

I've been trying to do this for a few days to no luck.
So basically i want my apache proxy to redirect the user to a tomcat on :8443. If i go to domain.com:8443 it displays the correct page but if i go to domain.com it comes up with a '401 Authorization Required' Page. I have it setup so my port 80 redirects to 443, and 8080 redirects to 8443 within tomcat config. 
default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com

        SSLEngine On

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I've tried to look everywhere but i can't find a solution that works for me.
Any help would be appreciated, I'm a beginner to all this :)

Edit- forgot to mention chrome says my cert is invalid if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Tomcat on port `8080` has a redirect and you proxy to that port, your reverse proxy will effectively perform a redirection, too. To fix this, you have two options:

- Remove the redirection from Tomcat's `8080` and make Tomcat only listen on the local loopback  (`localhost`, `127.0.0.1`). The local connection between the Apache and Tomcat doesn't need to be encrypted, as the Apache is terminating the TLS connection from the user.
- Reverse proxy directly to the HTTPS port `8443`:

  ```
  ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443/
  ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8443/
  ```